# Getting function scope variable value after declaring a global variable with the same name

Tags: php

so imagine I have this PHP code

```
<?php
    $var = 10;

    function foo($var)
    {
        global $var;
        echo $var;
    }

    foo(2);
?>
```

The output here is 10. I want to know if there is a way to refer back to the function scope variable $var (which in my example has a value of 2).

Comment: No. Once you declare a variable global within a function, any previous "local" version of that variable name is gone. You'd have to store the param in some OTHER variable.

Comment: Can you not name the function parameter something other than the global variable name?

Comment: @crush indeed I can, but then I don't have a question for SO now do I :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not an exact answer but here is a way:

```
$var = 10;

function foo($var)
{
    $array = get_defined_vars();
    global $var;
    echo $var;
    echo $array['var'];
}

foo(2);
```

You could also use `func_get_arg()` or `func_get_args()`, but whatever you do would need to be before the `global` statement.

Comment: Yea, i thought that this might be the only way, but wanted to check if there's perhaps a keyword of some sort that drives the declaration back to function scope.

Comment: And actually this would be the same as `$foo = $var;` and then accessing `$foo` later.